# How can I remove text in a table cell while keeping adjacent elements?

Tags: jquery

I have this HTML

```
<table> 
    <tr> 
        <td> <select id="foo"> 
                <option value="0" selected>0</option> 
                <option value="1" >1</option> 
            </select> 
            pcs 
        </td> 
    </tr> 
</table>
```

I need to remove the "pcs" string after `<select\>` with jQuery. How can I do that?

```
mmjQuery("#foo").parent().text(mmjQuery("#foo").parent().text().replace('db', ''));
```

But with that code the `select` DOM is manipulated.

Comment: Please search before posting. This was an easy one. Also take the [tour].

Comment: @isherwood I **should** have looked for the dupes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is save the `select` element to a `let` and then replace the content of the parent `td` with that element using `html()`:

```js
// Save the original select element here
let select_elem = $('#foo');

// use jQuery's html() method to pass the orignal select to overwrite the parent <td> content.
$('#foo').parent('td').html(select_elem);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select id="foo">
        <option value="0" selected>0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
      </select>
      pcs
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```